# How to Update Image path and save it back to database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

Here I add product and save path of image, everything works fine and image path is saved

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(Product p, HttpPostedFileBase prodImg, decimal[] price)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string absoluthFolderPath = Server.MapPath("\\Images");
                            string pathOfImage = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(prodImg.FileName);
                            string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + pathOfImage;
                            absoluthFolderPath += "\\" + newFileName;
                            prodImg.SaveAs(absoluthFolderPath);

                            string relitivePath = @"\Images\" + newFileName;
                            p.ImagePath = relitivePath;
                            p.Blocked = false;
                            new ProductsBL().AddProduct(p);
                            ViewData\["msg"\] = "Successfuly";
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return View();
                    }
```

When trying to update image path it gives me error shown on screenshot

```
 public ActionResult Update(Product modifieDetails, HttpPostedFileBase updImg)
            {
                string absoluthFolderPath = Server.MapPath("\\Images");
                string pathOfImage = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(updImg.FileName);
                string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + pathOfImage;
                absoluthFolderPath += "\\" + newFileName;
                updImg.SaveAs(absoluthFolderPath);

                string relitivePath = @"\Images\" + newFileName;
                modifieDetails.ImagePath = relitivePath;
                modifieDetails.Blocked = false;
                new ProductsBL().UpdateProduct(modifieDetails);
                return RedirectToAction("ListProduct");
            }

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgE88.png
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be a bit more specific with our question. What did you expect to happen? Were there any error messages?

Comment: The question says he wants to update it and save it back to the database, what's so confusing about that? IMO, this question is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split this up:

```
 new ProductsBL().AddProduct(p);
```

In order to save updates to an entity back to the store, you have to set "IsModified" on the entity, and then save the context. Like so...

```
using (ProductsBL context = new ProductsBL()) {
    var p = (some query to get it from the store);
    p.ImagePath = relitivePath;
    p.Blocked = false;
    p.IsModified = true;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As it is, you're creating a new entity and adding that to the store, not updating the existing one.

And, if you're coding in English, please fix the spellings: Modify, Relative, absolute.